# How to run test fixtures in order across multiple classes?

Tags: nunit

I have three classes all containing multiple tests. Each class has the annotation of TestFixture. I need each class to run the tests in order. (e.g. TextFixture1 runs all of its tests, then TestFixture2 runs all of its tests, and finally TestFixture3 runs all of its tests.) How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `OrderAttribute` on each fixture, specifying the order in which you want the fixtures to run. Use the same attribute on each test method, specifying the order the test should run **within the fixture**.

See `OrderAttribute` in the docs for more info.